# Can a database built with MySQLi be migrated successfully to MySQL database? Is backward compatibility possible?

Tags: mysql, mysqli, compatibility

I am going to build a Joomla 3 website using CloudAccess.net and I have to select Database Type. Here, I have been given both options MySQLi and MySQL.

Later I may want to move my Joomla site to go4hosting Linux shared hosting. Their package offers MySQL (no mention of MySQLi).

If I choose MySQLi now with CloudAccess.net and later move to MySQL with go4hosting will it work?

Or, should I select MySQL at the start itself with CloudAccess.net?

My limitations are that I am not a programmer. I am a computer enthusiast and I have built my website using Microsoft Expression Web and planning to go for Joomla.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysqli (Mysql improved) is only an inferface used by PHP to access a MySQL Database. The database itself is still a MySQL Database. This means, that you can access the same database both via the Mysql interface or via the Mysqli interface (or via other interfaces in other programming languages).

[Wiki MySQLi entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi)